# Space to URL in a batch file

Tags: url, batch-file, command

I am trying to start a URL with .bat file.
The problem is that I need to send space in the URL.
I created 2 variables (kw1,kw2)and i need to add space between them ,so it will be sent as a space to the browser. 
Adding + sign works but I need a different thing that I don't know because I need to do many tricks with the URL.

```
start www.imdb.com/%kw1%%kw2%
```

Comment: Try %%20 %20 is a space in a normal URL. You have to double them up in a batch file though.

Comment: i guess the only way to do it is to send + sign , which will be interpreted by most websites as an [AND] operators.               start %google%%kw1%+%kw2%^&s=all but i used cart [^] before [&] to escape the character.

Answer (score 2):

This will also work.

```
start "" "http://domain.com/url with space.html"
```

Comment: Yes it does.  But URLs are not supposed to have spaces in them unless they are hex encoded as  `%20` etc.  What error do you see?

Comment: My URL is hex encoded as %20. How do I replace the space in URL for it to work?